# How can I define the type for a <video> reference in React using Typescript?

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, dom, use-ref

I'm trying to control the play/pause state of a video using ref's in React.js, my code works but there are tslint errors I am trying to work through:

```
function App() {
    const playVideo = (event:any) => {
        video.current.play()
    }
    const video = useRef(null)

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <video ref={video1} loop src={bike}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

This will cause

```
TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.
```

So I try to change `const video = useRef(null)`
to `const video = useRef(new HTMLVideoElement())`

and I get:
`TypeError: Illegal constructor`

I have also tried: `const video = useRef(HTMLVideoElement)`
which results in:

```
TS2339: Property 'play' does not exist on type '{ new (): HTMLVideoElement; prototype: HTMLVideoElement; }'
```

Comment: It's a `<video>` element. Don't use the `src` attribute, use [<source>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/source) elements. Also, if this is actual React, use [createRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs) to create a ref.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) is the hook version of `createRef`.

Comment: ref={video1} should be ref={video}

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To set the type for the ref, you set the type like this: `useRef<HTMLVideoElement>()`. Then, to handle the fact that the object is possibly `null` (since it's null or undefined before the component is mounted!), you can just check whether it exists.

```
const App = () => {
  const video = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>();
  const playVideo = (event: any) => {
    video.current && video.current.play();
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <video ref={video} loop src={bike} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I saw this `useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null!)` syntax in Twilio's sample react app, and just could not figure out this syntax. I've never seen this before, and couldn't find it in the React documentation. Do you have a source with more information about it? Thanks

Comment: @Panpaper [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) is a React hook. `useRef(null)` initializes its value with null. `useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null)` is TypeScript which tells the compiler that the value stored inside the ref is of type `HTMLVideoElement`. The `<>` are related to [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html). The exclamation mark is called the [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator).

Comment: @Panpaper Not sure if the ! is needed there. Could depend on your TypeScript version and tsconfig settings.